# Spotify get user's playlists

Tags: spotify

Developping a spotify App, and I wanted to add dynamic playlist to user but I need to be sure that it's not already the case.

Is there a way to get the playlist of the current user using Spotify javascript API ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at this time, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks I'm then surprised that it was asked to me to not permit user to add a dynamic playlist again as it is impossible to already know existing playlist